# Using Typescript generics with react-apollo Query component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo, react-apollo

I am trying to wrap my Query component so that when an error is returned, an error message is displayed.  To this correctly with Typescript, my new component needs to use generics similar to the Query component in react-apollo.  When I try to pass the generics I accept for my wrapper, I get the following error.

```
Type '{ 
    children: (props: QueryResult<TData, TVariables>) => Element; query: any; 
    displayName?: string | undefined; skip?: boolean | undefined; 
    onCompleted?: ((data: TData) => void) | undefined; ... 9 more ...; 
    partialRefetch?: boolean | undefined; 
}' 
is not assignable to type 
'Pick<InferProps<{ 
    client: Requireable<object>; 
    children: Validator<(...args: any[]) => any>; 
    fetchPolicy: Requireable<string>; 
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: Requireable<boolean>; 
    onCompleted: Requireable<...>; ... 5 more ...; 
    partialRefetch: Requireable<...>; 
}>, Exclude<...> | ... 9 more ... | Exclude<...>>'.
```

Below is the code for the wrapper.  Could someone help me understand how to appropriately use generics and get rid of this error.

```js
import React from "react";
import ErrorMessage from "../components/ErrorMessage";
import { Query, QueryProps, QueryResult } from "react-apollo";

/**
 * This component can be used to to display error messages when a query
 * or mutation returns an error.  To do so, simply wrap a component
 * using the function dipslayError(Component) and use that instead of the
 * Query or Mutation component.
 *
 * Additionally, a function errorToMessage can be passed as a prop to the wrapped component.
 * This function will be ran on the returned error to convert the error into a message.  If
 * the function is not provided, the message displayed will be error.message.
 *
 */

export interface QueryWithErrorProps<TData, TVariables> extends QueryProps<TData, TVariables> {
    errorToMessage?: (error: Error) => string;
}

const QueryWithError = <TData, TVariables>(props: QueryWithErrorProps<TData, TVariables>) => {
    const { children, errorToMessage, ...rest } = props;
    let getMessage: (error: Error) => string;
    if (errorToMessage) getMessage = errorToMessage;
    else {
        getMessage = error => {
            return error.message;
        };
    }
    return (
        <Query<TData, TVariables> {...rest}>
            {(props: QueryResult<TData, TVariables>) => {
                const { error } = props;
                return (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        {children(props)}
                        {error && <ErrorMessage message={getMessage(error)} />}
                    </React.Fragment>
                );
            }}
        </Query>
    );
};
QueryWithError.displayName = "QueryWithError";
export default QueryWithError;
```

[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzdWn.png)

Comment: Usually, these kind of TypeErrors are more specific regarding which member of the implementation is missing, could you give more info about the error? Does it specify which member is missing in the source type that is included in the target type? It needs to be a subtype of the target to be compatible.

Comment: The only thing I can say for sure is wrong is that the return type of your generic's `children` member has a specific `Element` type, while the target type's `children` member has a return type of any, which is not assignable as a subtype. The target would have to either return `Element` as well or you can change the source return type to match the target, which you might or might not want.

Comment: As it might not be clear, the error for the <Query> node

Comment: See the picture now in the description.

Comment: I don't understand where you are seeing a return type of any from `children`

Comment: Another thing you could do is use a helper function to go through the target type and pick all the props that are required to implement the generic, and if it does you can safely do a type assertion.

Comment: `children: Validator<(...args: any[]) => any>; `

Comment: I see. But that's what's confusing about this, the actual props for Query are
`export interface QueryProps<TData = any, TVariables = OperationVariables> extends QueryOpts<TVariables> {
    children: (result: QueryResult<TData, TVariables>) => React.ReactNode;
    query: DocumentNode;
    displayName?: string;
    skip?: boolean;
    onCompleted?: (data: TData) => void;
    onError?: (error: ApolloError) => void;
}
`
I'm not even sure where the properties I am supposed have are coming from.

Comment: Here it says it's Element: `children: (props: QueryResult<TData, TVariables>) => Element;` just because the actual props are any or w.e doesn't mean Typescript can make that inference. It has to be exactly the same.

Comment: would you like me to post a super simple proof of concept as an answer?

Comment: Sure! Thanks Yesides

Comment: quick question, what version of react-apollo are you using?

Comment: 2.5.8, the most recent stable release